# Pass byte[] parameter to soap .Net from android

Tags: android, .net, soap

How can I send byte[] parameter to SOAP .net from android. How can check my sent byte[] is correctly arrive to SOAP as parameter. How can I receive byte[] from .Net?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the best way is to convert your byte array to a string.  There are several different encodings you can use in both languages (Java/.NET) but you probably want to use base64.  Search for converting byte array to string and you'll get the right answer.